# error when rendering partial in js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3 and have a problem.
I have remote form, and when I submit it I need to execute some js.
Here is my js.erb file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#block_login").remove();
$("#header").html("");
$("#header").html("<%= render :partial => "/layouts/header" %>");
});
```

in js console I have an error

```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.js:593
> jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery.js:593
> jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text script jquery.js:7175 ajaxConvert
> jquery.js:7074 done jquery.js:6622 jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

and this is cause of rendering.

Partial works fine, cause I have rendered it in html, and all was fine.
Here is my layouts/_header

```
<div id="header">
   <% if current_user.present? %>
       <div class="icon_1"><%= link_to 'Выход', logout_path %>
       <span>|</span><%= link_to 'Моя страница', user_path(current_user), :class => "registration"  %>    </div>
   <% else %>
       <div class="icon_1"><a href="#" onClick="block_login();">Вход</a>
       <span>|</span><%= link_to 'Регистрация', new_user_path, :class => "registration" %></div>
   <% end %>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="130px">
         <div class="logo"><%= image_tag "/images/logo.png" %></div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <div class="menu">
           <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
               <td>

               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

What i am doing wrong? THanks in advance!

Comment: OT, but, by the way...

    $("#header").html("");

    $("#header").html("<%= render :partial => "/layouts/header" %>");

The first one is useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's the quotation marks.
Try using:

```
$("#header").html("<%= render :partial => '/layouts/header' %>");
```

Instead of your code in:

```
$("#header").html("<%= render :partial => "/layouts/header" %>");
```